# WPF - Canvas.GetTop returning NeuN

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to get the position of a canvas from a mouse move handler but it returns NeuN.

The canvas is inside another canvas and the code is:

```
Console.WriteLine(Canvas.GetTop(canvas2));
```

this is inside:

```
private void move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(Canvas.GetTop(canvas2));
}
```

I'd say it can't be a scope problem because as SetTop works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a workaround. I'd still appreciate alternatives if somebody has a better way of doing this.

Basically, as GetTop doesn't work I thought I could get the RenderTransform object. And it worked!

```
canvas2.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
You can also do this:

```
Double current_y = (double)this.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
```